1h 10m international > domestic transit at IST (Istanbul) on a single ticket
We are travelling in August Mosow VKO -> Istanbul IST-> Antalya AYT on a single Turkish Airlines ticket with a 1 h 10 m connection in IST. Obviously, we will need to pass immigration during this time.
This sounds rather tight, and the airport is big... however, as the airline has sold us the tickets, hopefully they consider it doable. Also, there are several more flights to AYT the same day after our flight, so I hope that they will put us on the next flight if we miss our flight.
Anyway, is it realistic, in the first place? And are there any aids for passengers with short connection time — e.g. priority immigration for transfer passengers, etc?


hopefully they consider it doable.

Typically airlines & airports determine minimum connection times by collecting data on missed connections. If they sell you a ticket, then there is a good chance you will make it.

Also, there are several more flights to AYT the same day after our flight, so I hope that they will put us on the next flight if we miss our flight.

That is a nice backup to have. They are legally required to put you on the next available flight. In the very unlikely case these are all sold out, it depends on your negotiating skill. You can ask to be upgraded to seats in a higher class are available. You can also ask to be routed through a different city and/or using a different airline.
TK is the only carrier that serves IST -> AYT directly, but AJet and Pegasus fly out of SAW -> AYT.
If you are worried, it's a good idea to research available alternatives a day or two before departure and have them handy when discussing with TK staff.
If all else fails, they need to put you up in a hotel for the night and fly you out the next day.

Anyway, is it realistic, in the first place?

It's certainly not impossible, but there is no room for errors, delays, and unusually long lines at immigration or security. If you have any circumstances that make you slower (physical issues, larger group or family with small children, "difficult" passport or documentation, etc) it may be better to opt for the latter connection right away.

And are there any aids for passengers with short connection time — e.g. priority immigration for transfer passengers, etc?

You can always ask. Turkish Airlines isn't the most organized airlines I've flow with, so this may help or it may not.
